# Overwrite existing line in the middle of csv file in R?

Tags: r, csv

Is there a way to overwrite an existing line in the middle of a csv file with new data?

For instance, suppose I have this csv file:

```
V1,V2,V3,V4,V5
5,1,5,0,5
5,0,4,1,5
0,4,0,5,0
1,3,0,4,1
```

and suppose that I want to overwrite the third line (5,0,4,1,5) with other values, such as 1,1,1,1,1.

Is this possible? Would someone help me realize how to do so?

EDIT: the csv file doesn't fit in primary memory.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you care if the data gets imported and then written out again?

Comment: Other than read in the full file, change the data, and overwrite the old file with the new data?

Comment: You can overwrite a row in a data.frame like `dat[3,] <- list(1,1,1,1,1)`

Comment: The real csv file doesn't fit in primary memory. So it would be better just to write the specific line.

Comment: `dat[3,] <- c(1,1,1,1,1)` also works fine.

Comment: My problem is that I can't read the full file at once, since there is not enough space. Therefore, I have to read a specific line, change it, and then write it again.

Comment: You might be better off using a command-line-tool like `sed` to chew through it. R is probably not the best tool for the job if it's not going to be brought into memory.

Comment: @GabrielFGeislerMesevage - some of the time - assuming all columns are the same type it works okay, but `list` will work regardless.

Comment: @thelatemail The only problem in doing so is that some computation is already being made in R. If there were a way to just save the result in the csv file in the proper place, it would be a lot easier. If I can't find another solution, I'll do what you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: You could use a system call within R to run sed and overwrite the file.

Comment: Oh, I think now I really understood what you meant. Thanks.